# How can I add a view after the nib is loaded?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

Previously, I generate the programme using code, and I have a super class that have a background image all the time. But now I change my coding to using XIB, how can I insert a view after the Nib is loaded? But I don't want all my XIB have a view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awakeFromNib is the right method to use.  You don't want to cover up views by just adding the subview.  Insert the subview instead.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UIView *targetView;
    UIView *viewToInsert = [self pointerToViewToInsert];

    for (UIView *aSubview in self.view.subviews){
         if ([aSubview isEqual:self.someView]){
             targetView = aSubview;
             break;
         }
    }
    if (targetView){
        int targetIndex = [self.view.subviews indexOfObject:targetView];
        [self.view insertSubview:viewToInsert atIndex:targetIndex];
}
```

Comment: Glad to know *someone* could help him

Comment: The for loop can be left out in most cases.  Put it there to show how  to get the index of a subview matching certain criteria.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
  [view addSubview:newView];
}
```

Comment: It executes after the XIB is loaded, but I would like to have something before the XIB is loaded. For example, I have a button. In the awakeFromNib, I use add a label, the label is on top of the button, but I would like the label under the button.

Comment: Your question asks how to insert a view after the NIB is loaded. You can't add a subview to a view that has not yet been loaded.

Comment: You could just add the items in a different order @TedWong. Add the label then the button. Whala, they are in the order you want.